# Android get data from each ViewHolder of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android

How do I get data from each ViewHolder that has "false" for the data?

This is my adapter initialization

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Trace, TraceViewHolder>(Trace.class, R.layout.fragment_trace_item, TraceViewHolder.class, mDatabase))
{
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final TraceViewHolder viewHolder, final Trace model, final int position)
    {
        if(viewHolder.isAvailable == true)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my ViewHolder class

```
public class TraceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public boolean isAvailable;

    public TraceViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public void bindToTrace(final Trace trace, final Context context)
    {
        if(trace.value.equals("one")
        {
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        else(trace.value.equals("one")
        {
            isAvailable = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I have RecyclerView that has items that has either "one" or "two". What I am trying to do is to check if each ViewHolder (each item) has the value "one" or "two" and if the item has "one", it should toast "true", and if the item has "two", it should toast "false".

But when I run the program, it only toast "false" for all items.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Any Answer In My Qoestions in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901711/how-we-can-change-selected-activity

Answer (score 0):

You could create a callback to be called each time a view is binded to a data.

**YourActivity/YourFragment**

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.OnDataBindedListener listener = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.OnDataBindedListener {
    @Override
    public void onDataBind(boolean isAvaiable) {
        // Display toasts
    }
}

// Pass listener variable to constructor of your Adapter
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Trace, TraceViewHolder>(Trace.class, R.layout.fragment_trace_item, TraceViewHolder.class, mDatabase, listener);
```

**FirebaseRecyclerAdapter**

```
private final OnDataBindedListener listener;

public FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(..., OnDataBindedListener listener) {
    ...
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TraceViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Get your Trace object
    Trace trace = traceList.get(position);

    // Call the method implemented inside your activity/fragment
    listener.onDataBind(trace.value.equals("one"));
}


public interface OnDataBindedListener {
    void onDataBind(boolean isAvaiable);
}
```