# How we can change selected activity

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

The app is a University APP, My application contains two buttons in mainactivity(calicutuniversity  and mguniversity ), if we click on a button then it goes to the corresponding activity and saves that activity as the default for further application usage. 
     Now i need to try some more ideas into my application. I think you guys can help me for that. I need to.....
 * when we selects the university from the mainactivity and it goes to the corresponding activity. So if we need to change the activity we also have an option to change the selected university. By clicking change university ,it goes to main activity and then we can select another university and sets it as the default .

Will you please help me ??
My Code Below

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CardView cd1, cd2;
String clickedCard;
SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cd1 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.clt);
    cd2 = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.mg);


    checkPreferences();
    ////////Button1

    cd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent ButtonactivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CltActivity.class);
            clickedCard = "Button 1";
            ButtonactivityIntent.putExtra("fromMain1", clickedCard);
            startActivity(ButtonactivityIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    ///////////////Button2

    cd2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent ButtonactivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MgACtivity.class);
            clickedCard = "Button 2";
            ButtonactivityIntent.putExtra("fromMain2", clickedCard);
            startActivity(ButtonactivityIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    ///////////////Button3


}


private void checkPreferences() {

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref1", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (prefs.getString("txt1", "").equals("") || prefs.getString("lastActivity1", "").equals("")) {

        //do nothing
    } else {

        String txt = prefs.getString("txt1", "");

        String activity = prefs.getString("lastActivity1", "");
        Intent ButtonactivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CltActivity.class);
        ButtonactivityIntent.putExtra("fromMain1", txt);
        startActivity(ButtonactivityIntent);
        finish();

    }


    prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (prefs.getString("txt2", "").equals("") || prefs.getString("lastActivity2", "").equals("")) {

        //do nothing
    } else {

        String txt = prefs.getString("txt2", "");

        String activity = prefs.getString("lastActivity", "");
        Intent ButtonactivityIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MgACtivity.class);
        ButtonactivityIntent.putExtra("fromMain2", txt);
        startActivity(ButtonactivityIntent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

}

CalicutUniversity Activity

```
public class CltActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


String s;

SharedPreferences prefs;

Button buttonind;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clt);

    buttonind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonind);



    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if (bundle == null) {
        s = "no data received";
    } else {
        s = bundle.getString("fromMain1");
    }


    findViewById(R.id.buttonind).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showMenu();
        }
    });

    buttonind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mgButton2 = new Intent(CltActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mgButton2);
            finish();


        }
    });



}

private void showMenu() {


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref1", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("txt1", s);
    editor.putString("lastActivity1", getClass().getName());
    editor.apply();
}
```

}

Mguniversity Activity

```
public class MgACtivity extends AppCompatActivity {


String s;

SharedPreferences prefs;

Button buttonind;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mg_activity);

    buttonind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonind);



    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if (bundle == null) {
        s = "no data received";
    } else {
        s = bundle.getString("fromMain2");
    }


    findViewById(R.id.buttonind).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showMenu();
        }
    });

    buttonind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mgButton2 = new Intent(MgACtivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mgButton2);
            finish();


        }
    });



}

private void showMenu() {


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("pref2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("txt2", s);
    editor.putString("lastActivity2", getClass().getName());
    editor.apply();
}
```

}

Comment: Please, concise your actual problem and add relevant code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an Activity before your MainActivty.java that will check the SharedPreferences to load to the activity you want. I added an activity called ReallyEmptyActivity

here's the ReallyEmptyActivity.java

```
public class ReallyEmptyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_really_empty);

        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("UNIV", MODE_PRIVATE);

        String uni = preferences.getString("UNIV", "0");
        Log.d("LOAD", uni);

        if (uni.equals("0")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ReallyEmptyActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        } else if (uni.equals("uni1")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ReallyEmptyActivity.this, Uni1.class));
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(ReallyEmptyActivity.this, Uni2.class));
        }

        finish();

    }
}
```

This will act as your director to the specific activity as upon the user.
Your mainactivity.java will be the main screen where the user selects the university.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void uni1onclick(View view) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("UNIV",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor  editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString("UNIV","uni1");
        editor.commit();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Uni1.class));
    }

    public void uni2onclick(View view) {

        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("UNIV",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor  editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("UNIV","uni2");
        editor.commit();

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Uni1.class));
    }
}
```

when the user clicks the back button it'll take him back to the MainActivty where they can select the University again and when the app is re-run, the corresponding activity will be shown as the SharedPreference is getting overwritten.

Comment: So you don't want to save the last selected activity? Just remove the `SharedPreferences` code in the onClick functions. Add a button to go to the mainActivity

Comment: Please mark up the answers and comments you find helpful.

Comment: Then the code as mentioned in the answer should work absolutely fine. Checked it myself. Please mark up the answers and comments you find helpful

Comment: If you want to return to the university selection activity from the University activity add a button to call `startActivity()` and use it to return to the MAinActivity. I hope this is what you mean.

Comment: I never learnt the android programming or any such courses. I learnt from internet and by asking others. Now my app hav the mentioned problems . i will send you the code. Will you please help me to correct the code??
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0k-6wV_W5KeeWliTkF3VG82bkU/view

Comment: Do not add SHaredPref code in the onPause method. Because it is already saved while you're running the app.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html 
https://coderwall.com/p/n4qaaa/programatically-change-main-launch-activity-in-androidRead this, you'll find it helpful.

Comment: Follow the instructions I have said. You'll do it in no time. Stack doesn't mean we'll correct the whole code. Only parts like I have said in the above answer. Please upvote.

Comment: sir i want it save the last open activity (user choose university) evary time app open show that activity

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote.

Comment: i remove any code from main activity , mgactivity(university) and calicut activity (university)

Comment: hey i check it is working good, but a problom, selected a university then close app then re open app then show in 5 secont selected university (activity) then aoutometicly show mainactivity

Comment: add a finish() at the end of buuton click listeners of university selection activity.

Comment: If it's working please select the right answer to my answer.

Comment: thankyou. now this is working properly. after 1 months i have achieved my goal. you are the only one to give an answer for this. if i have any doubt  i shall ask you here after. can you please give me youyr email id?

Comment: Glad to help you. Please up vote the comments as well. Thank you.

Comment: if you wish , if i have any doubt i shall ask you here after. can you please give me youyr email id? –

Comment: pritubera@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

When the user is opening the app for the first time check the value of the Shared Preferences and it should take the default value if it does then open the MainActivity.

Else go to that particular activity.

And whenever the user chooses something from the MainActivity then just edit the contents of the Shared Preferences.

Comment: What do you want to do? Tell me?

Comment: when we selects the university from the mainactivity and it goes to the corresponding activity. So if we need to change the activity we also have an option to change the selected university. By clicking change university ,it goes to main activity and then we can select another university and sets it as the default .